# How to pass fit_params to fit a RandomizedSearchCV Getting index out of range error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to fit a RandomizedSearchCV with XGBRegressor estimator and would like to pass params to the fit method. In particular I want to set the stopping round and eval metric of XGBRegressor. The following code gives me index out of range error

```
xgb_fit_params = {'eval_metric': 'rmse', 
              'early_stopping_rounds': 50,
              'eval_set' :None
             }
xgb_param_grid = {'reg_alpha': [0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 3],
              'reg_lambda': [0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              'gamma':[0, 0.1, 0,5, 1],
              'colsample_bytree': [0.6,0.7, 0.8],
              'max_depth' : [4,5,6]
             }

model = xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=5, 
                    learning_rate=0.035, 
                    n_estimators=1000, 
                    silent=False, 
                    objective='reg:linear', 
                    min_child_weight=1, 
                    max_delta_step=0, 
                    subsample=1, 
                    scale_pos_weight=1, 
                    seed=2866) 

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, 
                               param_distributions=xgb_param_grid,
                               n_iter=20,
                               verbose=2,
                               n_jobs=-1,
                               fit_params=xgb_fit_params,
                               random_state=2866)
random_search.fit(X_train_all, y_train)
```

Comment: I don't know the package you are using... but the error means that one of the list do not contain enough elements. If you share the exact error we can be more helpful. BTW, assuming that there are no errors in the package itself, one of the list you define is too short...

Comment: You should post the complete stack trace of error here. Also why are you passing `None` to the `eval_set`. Are these fit_params working fine without the RandomizedSearchCV?

Comment: I think I figured it out. early_stopping_round requires an eval set param. Once removed it started to work. Thx.

Comment: Trying to run the same thing as you @Fred R., is there a way to pass `eval_set` through `fit_params`? Couldn't have it work so far...